# Foundation level Mathematics

Tags: real-numbers, proof-theory

I know this sounds absurd but I've always wondered this.
Is there any proof of $1+1=2$ and why $1+1$ can never be $3$, is there any proof for this too?

Comment: This may depend on your definitions fo $1, 2, 3, +, =$

Comment: I like this question _because_ it depends so much on how we define $1,$ $2,$ $3,$ $+,$ and $=.$

Comment: So in essence, these properties are variable?

Comment: That 1+1 cannot be 3 depends on the consistency of the Peano Axioms, which is a topic that's still being debated.

Answer (score 1):

Simply stated, it is not always true. For example
$$1+1=0 \text{ mod } 2$$

Thus, to be able to prove that $1+1=2$ and that $1+1 \neq 3$ you need to first specify what do you mean by $1,2$ and $3,$ what do you mean by $+,$ what do you mean by $=,$  etc...

Comment: So meaning of 1,2..... can be considered as postulate?

Comment: Hm... $1$ usually denotes a multiplicative identity. The meaning of $2,3,4,...$ is not always so simple. For example, take a look at the clock hanging on your wall. Can you see number $13$ there? Probably not. So what is $8+5$ on your clock? It cannot be $13,$ since $13$ doesn't exist....So I would say that $8+5=1$ on your clock, which is exactly the same as saying $$8+5 =1 \text{ mod } 12$$

Comment: One can also say that $13$ _does_ exist, but it is another name for $1$ modulo $12.$ Likewise $1+1\equiv 0 \equiv 2 \pmod2.$

Comment: Good point, @DavidK !